# PHP If statement to display more than 1 field if a value more than 1 is selected

Tags: php, mysql, select

What I want to do is to create a feature that creates fields based on what the user selects

For example;

```
<select name="ex">  
<option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>  
<option value="2">2</option>  
<option value="3">3</option>  
<option value="4">4</option>  
<option value="5">5</option>  
</select>
```

If the user selected 4, I want to be able to display 4 input fields

My question was, how would I construct a query that would do this?

I rattled my brain and all I could come up with was

```
if($ex='4') {
<input type="text" name="field4">
<input type="text" name="field4">
<input type="text" name="field4">
<input type="text" name="field4">
}
```

But there has to be an easier way of displaying them. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to SO,why you want the name to be same

Comment: I didnt wnt the name to be the same, it was just an example. I wanted the name to correspond with the fields selected

Comment: I believe a better way than any of these would be to do it on clientside, with `innerHtml` assignment or with `createElement`... but the tag does specify PHP. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If would be easier if you use `for` loop , like as follows :

```
for($i=1;i<=$ex;$i++){
 echo "<input type='text' name='field4[]'>";
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: If i used that, how would I give each field a unique name? I wanted the field name to correspond with however many fields were selected

Comment: Yes i changed the code now you can get the values of field4 in a array format

Answer (score 3):

You could even do it on the fly with javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/fudQF/

***Javascript:***

```
showFields(t) {
    f = document.getElementById('fields');

    while (f.childNodes.length >= 1)
        f.removeChild(f.firstChild);

    for(i = 0; i < t.value; i++) {
        e = document.createElement('input');
        e.setAttribute('type','text');
        f.appendChild(e);

        e = document.createElement('br');
        f.appendChild(e);
    }        
}
```

***HTML:***

```
<select name="ex" onClick="showFields(this)">  
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>  
    <option value="2">2</option>  
    <option value="3">3</option>  
    <option value="4">4</option>  
    <option value="5">5</option>  
</select>
<div id="fields">
</div>
​
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was talking about! :) +1

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i=0;$i<$ex;$i++)
{echo '<input type="text" name="field'.$i.'">';}
```

Try this
You can do this using onchange function in javascript on select

```
function chang()
{
for(var i=1;i<document.getElementById("select_id").value;i++)
document.body.innerHTML+='<input type="text" name="field"'+i+'>';
}
```

Comment: I recommend **always** using curly brackets, even if you are only using one statement in the code block - it prevents confusion in the future if you need to add more code to loop..

Comment: I answered depending on question but still i will make that change

Comment: ... especially if you don't indent properly.

Comment: What is confusing is the way you chose to indent your code - or more to the point - the lack of indentation... Writing code is only 1/3 of the solution... the other 1/3 is that it should work and the last 1/3 is that it can be easy to read for the next programmer that has to come along and add some functionality...  Your solution **is** correct - you just need to work on your presentation :)

Answer (score 1):

```
for($i = 0; $ < 4; $i++)
{
   echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"field".($i + 1)."\">";
}
```

Comment: @mitchell wanted all the textboxes with same name,i don't know why but she has written

Comment: I know I've just assumed it's not intended - it makes no sense to have inputs named the same

Comment: I didnt want them the same. I just wrote that as an example and hoped people would get the hint. Guess not

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($i=1; $i<=$ex; $i++)
{
   echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"field".$i."\">";
}
```

It will give unique name to your fields

Answer (score 0):

That `if` statement seems to be PHP (dollar sign before the variable).. I guess you want to echo or save in a variable that output.

A way to to that would be to use a repetitive statement (for, while) to do that thing the number of times you need.

Another option that is based on the fact that you seem to use the exact same output would be to use the [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/str_repeat) function.

That seems a bit strange.. maybe you want the name to be **`field4[]`** and not just **`field4`**

Comment: Fear not the capital letters ;)

Comment: @Lix :)) I guess I am saving the keyboard and extending the live of the shift key, but thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $ex=4

```
$ex=4;
for($C=1;$C<=$ex;$C++){ echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"field".$C."\" />"; }
```

Comment: Did you notice that two other people already have the exact same answer?

Answer (score 0):

Building on [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10617523/558021) - jQuery could further bring down the amount of code needed -

**HTML**

```
<select name="ex" onClick="showFields(this)">  
    <option selected="selected" value="1">1</option>  
    <option value="2">2</option>  
    <option value="3">3</option>  
    <option value="4">4</option>  
    <option value="5">5</option>  
</select>
<div id="fields">
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$("select[name='ex']").on('change',function(){
  var selectedVal = $(this).val();
  $("#fields").html(''); // clear existing input fields (possibly from previous selection)
  for (var i=1; i<=selectedVal; i++){
    $("#fields").append('<input type="text" name="field'+i+'">');
  }
});
```